# Keep focus on an application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have written an application which has a modal form. How can I ensure that this form does not lose the focus even when an other application is started?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a web application. Is that correct?

Answer (score 10):

Actually, this is exactly the sort of thing you shouldn't be doing.

There's too many programs around that assume they control the computer they're installed on.  It is the user of your application that should be in control.

That's why later versions of Windows disallowed stealing of focus instead insisting on just blinking the entry in the task list bar.

You may well find a way to do it (though I doubt it), but I urge you to rethink it.  I'd be interested in knowing why you thought it was necessary.

Comment: I wrote an application to hear to web radio stations while I am on my bicycle ergometer. I can change the stations by pressing a button on the game pad that is fixed on the ergometer. When the focus of the application is lost I am no longer able to use the game pad.

Comment: I use the directX-Framework. When the focus of the application is lost I can't read the data any more.

Comment: Actually I retract my earlier comment: if it's software for your own use, you have a valid reason for keeping focus. Perhaps a question you should be asking is "how can I stop other apps from stealing my focus?"

I would have thought that, while you're on your bike, no other apps would start.

Comment: There are different actions, for example i can start you tube videos with the application. some videos cause script errors and because of that the browser control shows a pop up and the focus of the main form is lost.

Comment: You can use the DirectX (DirectInput I assume you are using) to read the data in a "promiscous" mode from the devices.  I wrote a little app that let you use a game pad as a mouse, no matter which application had focus.  If that is what you want, use SetCooperativeLevel with CooperativeLevelFlags.NonExclusive | CooperativeLevelFlags.Background as the flags.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the "Topmost" property to true to keep the form in front of all others but that doesn't make it keep focus.

Answer (score 0):

You must make the dialog system modal.

Comment: "You must the dialog system modal." needs to be re-worded to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
SetForegroundWindow(Me.Handle)
```

Me.Handle is the handle of your form.

You need to declare the following somewhere in your class or winform, but not inside a function

```
Declare Unicode Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
```

You might need to initiate a timer and call SetForegroundWindow on every tick of say 10 seconds, depending on your preference.

EDIT: It works for me, if it doesn't add the following

```
    Declare Unicode Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SystemParametersInfoW" (ByVal uiAction As Int32, ByVal uiParam As Int32, ByRef pvParam As Int32, ByVal fWinIni As Int32) As Int32
```

And surround SetForegroundWindow with these

```
    Dim _timeout As Int32
    SystemParametersInfo(&H2000, 0, _timeout, 0)
    SystemParametersInfo(&H2001, 0, 0, 3)
    SetForegroundWindow(Me.Handle)
    SystemParametersInfo(&H2001, 0, _timeout, 2)
```

That's the last resort